# Crawl only articles/content

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

I want a crawler to be able to identify which pages on, for example, a news site, are actual content (i.e. articles), as opposed to About, Contact, category listings, etc.

I've found no elegant way about this so far, as the criteria for content seem to vary by site (no common tags/layouts/protocols, etc.).  Can anyone direct me either to libraries or methods that can identify with some level of certainty whether a website is a piece of content?  It's perfectly acceptable to make this distinction after I have crawled the candidate page.

Barring anything that already exists, I'd also appreciate any starting points to existing/ongoing research in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking [Boilerpipe framework](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) . There is online extraction demo available from their project's page. If extraction result is not very good for your case, you need to extend their algorithm.